# In Extjs5, erase() can't relate to destory api when the proxy type is rest

Tags: rest, extjs5

This is my viewController:

onRestDeleteClick: function(){

```
var ouType = Ext.create('MyApp.model.OuType',
 {
  id: 49,
  ouTypeName: 'Lenlee', 
  entityName: 'Lenlee'
 });
 ouType.erase();
}
```

The model whose id is 49 exists in database.

This is the OuType model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.OuType', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  requires: [
  'Ext.data.field.Field'
],

fields: [
  {
   name:'id'
  },
  {
   name: 'ouTypeName'
  },
  {
   name: 'entityName'
  }
],
proxy:{
  type: 'rest',
  api: {
     read: 'role/read',
     update: 'role/update',
     create: 'role/create',
     destory: 'role/destory'
   }
 }
});
```

This is my server class:

```
 @RequestMapping("/role")
 @Controller("sysRoleContro")
 public class SysRoleController {
     …………
     …………
      @RequestMapping(value="/destory/{id}")
      public void destoryOuType(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("id") Long id){ 

          log.info("destory");
          ouTypeRepository.delete(id);
          log.info("end");
     }
 ………
 ……

}
```

Now when i click the delete button, the request url is: http://localhost:7080/MyApp.model.OuType/49 404 Not Found.

The expected url is http://localhost:7080/CSQMS/role/destory/49

How can i delete the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to say i'm so careless, i should write 'destroy' instead of 'destory'. MY GOD.

Answer (score 0):

Rest proxy is special in that that it does not CRUD operations to urls, as you set in api, but to HTTP verbs: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. So `api` config is most likely ignored. Configure the proxy this way:

```
proxy:{
    type:'rest',
    url:'/CSQMS/role'
}
```

If your server expects that CRUD operation verb is part of the URL you probably need a different proxy or you need to implement [`buildUrl`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest-method-buildUrl) method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have attempted to execute create, update and read operations with api of rest proxy. It's successful.  Save() in Ext.data.Model can really relate to create api of rest proxy, and load() in Ext.data.Model can really relate to read api of rest proxy, also first set() then save() in Ext.data.Model can really relate to update api of rest proxy. Only erase() can't do it. Here is my confusion.